# How can I make a method execute when any main has completed using the java object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, rmi

I have a Java object that is a client in a RMI model and the RMI server implements a locking mechanism that only allows access from one client at a time. In order for the server to be made available for a new client, the existing client must remove its lock by calling a `disconnect()` method before its thread dies.

The issue I'm having is that if the client doesn't call `disconnect()`, the server will never free up.

**Is it possible to enforce that whenever ANY main making use of the client has finished running, it calls `disconnect()` WITHOUT specifying so in the main?**

I read about the `finalize()` method which is called during garbage collection, but from my understanding it is extremely unreliable.

Comment: First off you should use a timeout to free up the server. As for `finalize()`: a shutdownhook could do the job. Nevertheless you need to take the following into consideration: if the JVM terminates unexpectedly (e.g. pulling the plug of the computer), the JVM won't clean up anything. So in the end you'll have to use a timeout anyways.

Comment: I agree with Paul. There are multiple ways you can handle it:
1) finalize() , less reliable 
2) Use finally() ? 
3) Add a shutdown hook to client. so if client is dying normally (like ctrl + c) it will get called
4) Have a heartbeat from client to server. And configure server to disconnect a client if it misses N number of heartbeats.

Comment: I would ask why? Concurrent access isn't difficult to implement. Or you can give each client its own instance of a remote object to play with, and use `Unreferenced.unreferenced()` if you need to. Why deliberately build in a bottleneck? with an API?

Comment: @EJP I need to control access because it is an API to control a hardware unit. If 2 users are changing the hardware at the same time, it will not perform as either client expects.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal I was also planning on using a timeout feature on top of this. As for shutdownhooks, I thought that these were only for implementing code to be called when a specific main has finished running. I don't want the user of my API to have to specify a shutdownhook. Heartbeat may be a good idea. Maybe a timeout with finalize() will be good enough.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to bundle up all the changes locally and execute them in a single RMI call? Rather than provide a series of remote API calls that you have to wrap a transaction around somehow?

Comment: @EJP In the long run thats what I'm going to do but not at this point of my development. That wouldn't change the issue at hand, however. I still want one user to be able to lock the hardware to themself over the period of time that they are using it.